# Help in presenting navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need help on some logic.
This is how my application is structured.

Welcome View Controller > Login View Controller > Tab Bar Controller > Feed Navigation Controller

So, i used presentmodal for the transition of Welcome View Controller to Login View Controller.
using `[self presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:YES];`

So now i'm in Login View Controller. But how to i navigate to the Tab Bar Controller which will show the rootviewcontroller of the Feed Navigation Controller?

I tried `[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];`
But i'm not getting the navigation controller in it!

Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't thoroughly read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) you should, and then reformulate your design and question.

Answer (score 0):

If `TabBarController` is your rootController, then your implementation is probably wrong.

Have the Welcome Screen as your `ModalViewController` and **Navigate** to LoginScreen, and perform necessary actions.

```
if (LoginSuccessful)
 // Dismiss modalview controller
```

This will bring control back to your rootController, and you do not need to navigate from welcome to login to tab bar and stuff like that.

Comment: Welcome screen is my rootController. However i would like to on login success, change the view to the tabbarcontroller with feed navigation controller shown.(my tabbarcontroller have 4 navigation controller in it). Thank for your reply!

Comment: THEN  your tabbarcontroller should be your `rootViewController` ! Good Luck !